# wp_get_archives() output

Tags: functions, blog, wp-get-archives

Iv got this code in my blog.php:

```
<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly', 'limit' => 12 ) ); ?>
```

It links to:

> /2013/01

My page only loads the header and footer - I think its the main loop - what do I have to do, do I need another file?
Or say where to output the code?

Thanks..

Comment: There is not enough information here to help. In what way does the page not load? Redirect? Blank page? What? Is there a public URL that you can provide?

Comment: I got that code in blog.php its my "page of posts" file, when I click on januari 2013 i got a page with only my header and footer

Comment: Do you have any posts that were created in January 2013?

Comment: yes: 7 januari 2013 @ 15:10 this is my website: http://www.finsens.salescaredev.nl/-expat-services/newsletter

Comment: Ok this really really sucked I had my function in my archives.php but it needs to be in archive.php so I removed 1 character and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `date.php`, `archive.php`, and `index.php` files control the date archive output. You need to check the contents of those files, in respective order, to find the problem.

If WordPress can't find `date.php`, it will check for `archive.php`, and load that if found. Otherwise, `index.php` will be used to display date archives.

[See my answer on a previous question for more information](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78541/19726)