# Which file displays the date archive?

Tags: posts, widgets, calendar

I'm building a new theme. I'm now working on to figure out which file is needed to show the "whole" post for a specific date which displays when you click on a date in the built in WordPress calendar widget?

Somebody who has a clue which it is?

Comment: Are you talking about the calendar sidebar widget?

Comment: Exactly bungeshea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`archive.php` is used to display author, search, category, tag and **date** archives. As clicking on a calendar day will take you to the date archive for that day, then the file you're looking for is `archive.php`.

More specifically, WordPress will check for these files in this order, stopping when it finds one of these files in your active theme's folder:

1. `date.php`
2. `archive.php`
3. `index.php`

[Read more at the WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Date_display)